# Libreoffice impress doesn't work on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, libreoffice

I recently installed the `libreoffice-ogltrans` package for more transitions in Impress. When I checked, most of the new transitions weren't working. I thought this was related to OpenGL, and so I enabled OpenGL in LibreOffice settings.

Now when I start Impress, all I get is a flickering black and white window with horizontal lines in the places text should have been. No icon or UI element is visible, just black and white rectangles.

I have a Nvidia GeForce GT 705 card with the recommended `nvidia-390` drivers.

Comment: I assume that you mean "OpenCL" instead of "GL"?  Can you start Libre office writer, and disable "OpenCL" from the settings in that application?

Comment: I meant "OpenGL". And no I can't start writer as the problem affects all LibreOffice apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this the easy way first:

Open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), and enter the command

`libreoffice --safe-mode`

In the window (that should open)  choose "Configure" and "Disable Hardware Acceleration (OpenGL/OpenCL), then "Apply changes and Restart"

Then close this application, and open LibreOffice Impress or LibreOffice Writer.

[image]

---

A slightly mode difficult way to do this would be to re-write all of the user configurations for LibreOffice.  To do this, Open a terminal window and enter the command

`mv ~/.config/libreoffice ~/.config/libreoffice.bak`

This will reset all user LibreOffice configurations to 'stock'

Comment: Thanks. LibreOffice works now, but the transitions still do not.

Comment: @AdityaArsh It does seem that about 1/2 of the transitions do not work.  I'd suggest filing a bug at LibreOffice, although they apparently know that many of the transitions don't work.